# Remote Fax Console (fxsclnt.exe) on Win8

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-8, fax

My boss just upgraded from WinXP to Win8 (finally!) and used to have a program c:\windows\system32\fxsclnt.exe which opened a Microsoft Fax Console that let her see a log of all incoming/outgoing faxes from our Win2003 server that is running MS Fax Services.  She also had another similar shortcut to send a fax.

On Win8 I'm looking at the "Fax and Scan" UI (it is installed) but I'm not seeing any options to connect to a remote PC to manage/view that one.  Is this no longer possible with Win8 or do I just need to install something?

It is Win8 Pro.  I can't really just switch to a 3rd party solution because we have several others (still on XP) using this existing system, at least for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Fax and Scan select the Tools menu and then Fax Accounts. Click Add to add the Fax server. I can verify this works when connecting to a Windows 2008 or 2008 R2 server running the Fax service.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I'm getting a security error when I attempt to do these steps (after entering server name), but I imagine I'll either figure that out or start another question.